# Change the default sort option in product listing page

Tags: spartacus-storefront

In the product listing page, the default sort option is by "**relevance**". Is there a way to change this to say by **price**?

Comment: The `placeholder` seems to be hardcoded to `relevance`. I've created an issue for that https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/7333

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A github issue was created in our repo: https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/7333. Please follow that issue for more info.